# Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL. while testing javascript code having defer()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, sinon, jasmine-node

i have the following code  in FormService.js

```
service.retriveFields = function (Id,UniqueIds) {

        var deferred = $q.defer();

        function success(successResponse) {
            // valid response received
            if (successResponse.data) {
                deferred.resolve(successResponse.data);

            } else {
                // TODO: show error message
                console.log("error");

                deferred.reject(response);
            }
        }

        function error(errorResponse) {
            console.log(errorResponse);
            deferred.reject(errorResponse);
            // TODO: show error message
        }

        // service call
        SomeFactory.retriveFields(Id, UniqueIds)
            .then(success, error);

        return deferred.promise;
    };
```

I have written the following  test case

describe('retriveFields ()', function () {

```
    it('tests function call', function (done) {

        var response = {data: {}};
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var promise = deferred.promise;
        promise.then(function () {
            resolve(response);
        });

        var Id = "5b7d86e60bf5e5bc21b4309f";
        var UniqueIds = ["5b7d71b822fc4e102c0875d3", "5b7d71ad2d4914162cb12ec6"];



        sinon.stub(SomeFactory, 'retriveFields')
            .returns($q.when(response));

        var promise = FormService.retriveFields (Id,UniqueIds);
        promise.then(function (result) {
            expect(result).toEqual({data :{}});
        })
    });
});
```

however i got the following error

Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.

I am not understanding as to why the timeout is happening . Am i testing incorrectly ?

if yes please help me as to how can i test defer

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you aren't calling `done()` to let `Jasmine` know to stop waiting for your test to complete.

Comment: @user_531 let me know if this covers what you need or if you have additional questions